# Login form with c# with I.P. Board API?

Tags: c#

Hello so I am trying to make a c# application to login using my websites user credientals but I am only getting a url and I can't figure out how to get the data to then execute the url with the textbox text

This is the URL: https://americandreamrp.com/index.php?/login/

I can't see to find the post data that is triggered when logging in and IPS software doesn't give you no reference to login API just all the other stuff :/

I would appreciate whatever help comes my way. Thank you.

Comment: Is that the response? Just a url? Are you parsing / handling the response object?

Comment: right yes, when I try to login the url doesn't change.

Comment: Do you have access to this site? You need to use oauth or some equivalent in order to do cross server access.

Comment: Yes I do, is their documentation on that?

Comment: @wahwahwah I couldn't find none.

Comment: Bump please. Trying to still do this.

Comment: Can you update your post to eliminate some of the options? You have 1) the board config, 2) the IPS library, 3) the req-resp data.... I think you're not getting good feedback because there's a volume of issues that might silently fail in this process.

Comment: Because there's only a link, this looks like spam

Comment: i'll just use a new database and do it that way.