# How would you add new text on the new line of a specific text in code in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#

so I have a file with comments

```
--members
name
name
name


--vip
name
name
name
```

the richtextbox is populated by a text file but i'm trying to find

"--members"
append line here

or if I have a vip then find

"--vip"
append line here

I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Just pass "vip" or "members" in the category

```
            public void AddPerson(string category, string name)
    {
        // Append person under this header
        var lines = txtMembers.Lines.ToList();

        // First find the line of the category
        var header = txtMembers.Lines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.StartsWith("--" + category));

        // If we don't have this category, add it
        if (header == null)
        {
            lines.Add("--" + category);
            txtMembers.Lines = lines.ToArray();

            header = txtMembers.Lines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.StartsWith("--" + category));
        }

        // Find index of header
        var headerIndex = lines.IndexOf(header);
        lines.Insert(headerIndex + 1, name);

        txtMembers.Lines = lines.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting this for var header

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element' but I did a messagebox and it shows. but yes you have goal in mind for sure.

Comment: If you're getting an InvalidOperationException it's because your RichTextBox doesn't contain a line "--vip" or "--members" or you're not passing "vip" or "members" to the method "category" argument. Is your RichTextBox empty to start?

Comment: Edited the answer to add the category if it doesn't exist as a line already

Comment: no it is not, and here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/ne9wky, http://prntscr.com/ne9www

Comment: then you do not have a line starting with --members. Are there any spaces before "--members"? I have this Form and mine is working fine. https://prntscr.com/ne9yg4  and https://prntscr.com/ne9yo4

Comment: ahh yes there is a tab to keep it in the code block

Comment: then you need to modify l.StartsWith("--" + category) to change it to l.StartsWith("\t--" + category)

Comment: mind if I rattle your brain about getting the files directory for my auto updating?

Comment: Sure, what's the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756196/login-form-with-c-sharp-with-i-p-board-api